# 2 javascript code clashing

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript and just started small codings and sometimes running readymade codes...

Today, I used www.dynamicdrive.com   Site for readymade javascript codes of which, clock and always top message is used ...

Both are working fine separately... But, when I combined both in one html page either of them is showing...

There is no names related conflicts but still this problem exists..

clock code is in same html page... while topmsg.js file is separately available which is used in html page code using  tag..
Following is the error shown using Mozilla firefox.. Any body can resolve this problem of 2 javascript codes clashing...

[image]

Comment: document.all is from 1990, find better code.

Comment: The warngin is saying the line that says `document.all...` should be `document.getElementById("elementId")...`

Comment: but both codes are running separately fine..

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. The code is outdated.

Comment: It seems both scripts declare their (numerous) variables in the global scope. The second script must be overwriting some variables or functions of the first script. This seems like really outdated js programming

Comment: yes.. code shows warning but it runs separately as i told.. actually its onload event used in body tag and window.load clashing .. When i have used other clock it worked.. some outdated codes are creating problems.. I agree.. But In Internet.. to resolve windows.load and onload conflict solution is given which i am unable to get .. as i am beginner i am curious more to learn and know single detail.. atleast this small one..

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the scripts overwriting each other's onloads, then there's a way to avoid that.

Lets say a script does this

```
window.onload=someFunction;

function someFunction(){
...
}
```

then you can change it to

```
var myOldOnloadFunc = window.onload;

function someFunction(){
  if(typeof(myOldOnloadFunc)=='function')myOldOnloadFunc();
   ...
}
```

You should probably do that for each script (since you don't know which is called first), just make sure you use myOldOnloadFunc for one script and myOldOnloadFunc2 for the other.

If you get stuck, seeing the associated code would help.